# Error converting value \"failed\" to type > 'System.Nullable

Tags: tfs

I have the following code to retrieve the build history using API and TFS2013.

```
var connection = new VssConnection(uri, cred);
var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
var builds = buildServer.GetBuildsAsync($"{teamProjectName}").Result;
```

When calling buildServer.GetBuildsAsync I get the following error

> {"Error converting value \"failed\" to type
>   'System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildStatus]'.
>   Path 'value[0].status', line 1, position 268."}

Any idea what this could mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To work with XAML builds you need to use either the older version of
>   the REST client or preferably the SOAP client. As XAML is being
>   deprecated we have removed those defintions from the latest version of
>   the REST apis. Refer to [this case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/82465/tfs-can-not-get-the-xaml-build-definitions-when-us.html).

I've tested with TFS 2015 (we don't have TFS 2013 environment right now). If use 15 version of `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`, this api can't get XAML builds. If use 14 versions of `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`, this api can get XAML builds successfully.

If this api can't work even though using 14 versions of `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`, please try using the old api below to retrieve XAML builds:

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/teamprojectcollection"));
        tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
        IBuildServer buildserver = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
        IBuildDefinition[] buildDefinitions = buildserver.QueryBuildDefinitions("teamproject");
        IBuildDetail[] builds = buildserver.QueryBuilds("teamproject");
```